# how come high velocity fluids creates higher pressure drop? and if it does how the flow is possible inside horizontal heat exchanger?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, velocity, flow

Why does high velocity fluid create a high pressure drop?   If it creates a high pressure drop inside unit operation equipment, then how is the flow possible?

Comment: You question makes no sense. High-velocity fluid by itself "creates" nothing (and, of course, if it's uniform velocity you are talking about then whether the velocity is high or not is observer-dependent).

Answer (score 1):

high velocity flow generates more viscous losses than low velocity flow. those viscous losses are responsible for the pressure drop. so high velocity flow means more pressure drop. the flow is possible because the unit operation equipment is being fed by a pump or by gravity, which furnishes the power required to move the fluid. Therefore, high velocity flow requires high power pumps.

Comment: The Bernoulli principle depends on viscous losses? Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: He was not talking about the Bernoulli principle, or so one would hope. It's unclear what the OP was talking about.

Comment: I wasn't talking bernoulli at all, Peter. As indeed one would hope... just first order engineering effects:  subsonic flow through a pipe,  incompressible fluid,  finite viscosity,  and resultant pressure losses.